# Alternating Integers in a bit string

Tags: javascript, binary

I am working on a leetcode question that requires writing a formula that determines whether or not a bit string for a given number `n` has alternating integers.

I feel like my logic is solid, but I think there is something wrong with the way I define the bit string and loop through it. Can someone help me find why this code is not working? Thanks, I am self taught and this is my first stab at a javascript leetcode, so any advice is appreciated!

```js
//first we need to create a variable that is a string of the bits for whatever number is given

//create variables current and previous and set them to null
//create for loop that loops through each digit in the bit, and sets "current" the number being looped over
//is that value = to previous (null on first loop)? no, continue loop and set previous to current
//run through loop again, changing current value
//is current = previous? if yes, result = false
//if no, continue loop


//define function
var hasAlternatingBits = function(n) {
  let current = null; //set current to null so first loop iteration is always ture
  let previous = null; //previous is null so it can be changed during loop
  let result = true; //result is true until loop finds consecutive integers
  var bitString = n.toString(2).split(', '); //turn string into an array that can be looped

  //create for loop that loops entire string, or until it finds two consecutive integers
  for (let i = 0; i < bitString.length; i++) {
    //set value of current to number being looped over in string
    current = i;
    //if current doesnt equal previous, 
    if (current !== previous) {
      previous = current; //set previous to current
    } else //if current does equal previous
      result = false; //change return to false
    break; //end loop
  }

  return result;
};

console.log(hasAlternatingBits(5)) // should return true
console.log(hasAlternatingBits(7)) // should return false
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of a parameter and what is expected

Comment: @RenaudC5 sure, if n is 5, the result should be true because the binary representation of 5 is 101. If n is 7, the result would be false because the binary representation of 7 is 111. Basically if the binary representation of a given number has two consecutive repeating integers, return false

Comment: It should be `n.toString(2).split("")` without the `", "` delimiter. Another problem is that you aren't comparing characters; you're comparing indices instead, which makes it always false. You need to use `bitString[current]` and `bitString[previous]` to compare them.

Comment: @RenaudC5 thank you very much. It works now. This stuff feels great to get figured out! cheers

Comment: Glad to help, do not hesitate to mark answer as resolved ;)

Answer (score 3):

The main problem was that you were assigning `current` to i so it took the value from 1 to the length of `n`

Note also that you can loop through string as you loop through array as i did in the following snippet

---

Note also that you break was outside the `else` part of the code.

In your code you can just `return false` if `previous === current` and then save some time

```js
//define function
var hasAlternatingBits = function(n) {
    let current = null; //set current to null so first loop iteration is always ture
    let previous = null; //previous is null so it can be changed during loop
    let result = true; //result is true until loop finds consecutive integers
    let bitString = n.toString(2);//turn into string
    
    //create for loop that loops entire string, or until it finds two consecutive integers
    for (let i = 0; i < bitString.length; i++) {
        //set value of current to number being looped over in string
         current = bitString[i]; // <-- here
        //if current doesnt equal previous, 
        if (current !== previous) {
            previous = current;//set previous to current
        }
        else { //if current does equal previous
            return false
        }
    }
    
    return result;
};

console.log(hasAlternatingBits(5))
console.log(hasAlternatingBits(7))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my shot on this:

```
n == 0 || n.toString(2).split("").every((n, i) => n != i % 2)
```

Explanation:

The `every` function will iterate over the list and accumulate the true results. It has the optional parameter `i` that is the iterator index. The result of i % 2 itself alternates between 0 and 1 for increasing values of i.

```js
var fn = n => n == 0 || n.toString(2).split("").every((n, i) => n != i % 2)

console.log(fn(5))  // true
console.log(fn(7))  // false
console.log(fn(11)) // false
console.log(fn(21)) // true
console.log(fn(0))  // true
console.log(fn(1))  // true
```